# Is Python Object Instance a unique object in the language?

Tags: python, list, object, python-3.x

I am wondering about how Python handles the user-defined objects. So here is the scenario:

I have created my own class called MyClass:

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self):
    # some code here

class MyClassContainer():
  def __init__(self):
    self.container = [] # will store MyClass object instances.
  def Add(self, object):
    self.container.append(object)
  def Remove(self, object):
    self.container.remove(object)

example = MyClassContainer()

myclass1 = MyClass()
example.Add(myclass1)

myclass2 = MyClass()
example.Add(myclass2)

example.Remove(myclass1)
```

So the question, is python's remove function able to distinguish different object instances of the same class? Is there any corner case that will not uniquely identify the object instance I wanted to delete?

A possible scenario is this one:

```
myclass1 = MyClass(5)
example.Add(myclass1)

myclass1 = MyClass(3)
example.Add(myclass1)

example.Remove(myclass1)
```

Which object instance will be removed? I guess the one with 3 passed, but is there a rule that says, python uniquely identify object instances of the same class?

Comment: you have to define how they are compared using `__eq__`. Basically locates the `myclass1 == example.container` element and removes that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.remove()` removes the first object that tests *equal*. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

> `s.remove(x)`
>    remove the first item from *s* where `s[i] == x`

Instances of a custom class by default only test equal if they are the exact same object; if `s[i] is x` returns true then `s[i] == x` also returns true.

It is not the variable name that defines the instance; in your second example, it'll be the `MyClass(3)` instance that is removed from the list, because it is a unique object, distinct from the `MyClass(5)` instance you created and added before. You can check this with the [`id()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), which on CPython basically returns the current memory address:

```
>>> myclass1 = MyClass(5)
>>> id(myclass1)
4349144816
>>> example.Add(myclass1)
>>> myclass1 = MyClass(3)
>>> id(myclass1)
4349145040
>>> example.Add(myclass1)
>>> example.container
[<__main__.MyClass object at 0x1033aaef0>, <__main__.MyClass object at 0x1033aafd0>]
>>> hex(id(myclass1))
'0x1033aafd0'
>>> myclass1 is example.container[1]
True
>>> example.Remove(myclass1)
>>> example.container
[<__main__.MyClass object at 0x1033aaef0>]
```

Note that the default representation of your custom classes include the `id()` value in hexadecimal!

You can alter this behaviour by overriding the [`object.__eq__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__); have it return `True` or `False` based on your own criteria, or return the `NotImplemented` singleton if the other object is not a type your class supports being compared with (so Python can delegate to the other object).

For example, if your instances should be considered equal when their `number` attribute is equal, you'd implement it like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyClass):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.number == other.number
```

With that change, you can do this:

```
example.Add(MyClass(42))
example.Add(MyClass(81))
example.Remove(MyClass(42))
```

and that would remove the instance with `number` set to `42`.

Comment: And if you were on Python 2, while you're defining `__eq__`, you'd want to either set `__hash__ = None` or define a reasonable `__hash__` method, so dicts and sets don't go crazy.